# Errors as runtime after adding gems to Gemfile and deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, bundler, unicorn

We have a rails 3.2 app in development and are deploying to a Linux VPS using pretty much the instructions in this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps except we are using rvm instead of rbenv. We are using nginx, unicorn, rvm, rails 3.2 and postgres.

The initial `cap deploy:cold` ran fine and we have made several deployments since without changing the gems from the initial deploy.

We have now added will_paginate and related code and deployed as usual with `cap deploy`. The deployment runs without any errors and I can see the call to `bundle install --path /home/..../shared/bundle --deployment` (with some other options).

The problem is that when we visit the page of the app that uses will_paginate we see the following error in the logs: `NoMethodError undefined method paginate`.

So that says to me that the gem isn't available to the rails app for some reason.

I've ssh'ed into the box and if I run `bundle list` I can see will_paginate listed. If I check the bundle location from above (/home/..../shared/bundle), will_paginate is there.

I've restarted unicorn, still no joy. I guess it's some kind of path issue but I don't know why the other gems are available but new ones are not.

Any ideas how I can go about debugging this issue?

The project is open source and is on github so you can see the various config files here: https://github.com/andypike/lagtv

Thanks in advance

Andy

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this same issue.  The only way I can get unicorn to "refresh" (if that's the right word) is to manually stop unicorn, then start it again.  On my system it's:

```
    /etc/init.d/unicorn_appname stop
    /etc/init.d/unicorn_appname start
```

Restarting serves me fine for deployments, but any adjustments to the Gemfile requires me to start/stop.